# Java Language Specification: meaning of notation |S|

Tags: java, types, casting, type-conversion, jls

I am going through the *JLS 7* to understand the type casting *[Section 5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)*.

It says: Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type
T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur
due to the following rules.
If S is a class type:

- If T is a class type, then either ***|S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|***. Otherwise, a compile-time
  error occurs.

They made it clear if S and T are two types in *[Section 4.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10)*, then

- *S :> T* indicates S is a super type of T
- *S > T* indicates S is a proper super type of T which implies *S :> T* and *S != T*.

I am not able to find the meaning of ***|S|***. Please help me understand what does it mean by ***|S|***? Does it mean the number and types of properties or something else. I tried to search for it in *JLS* itself but couldn't find it's meaning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I found: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6 "We write |T| for the erasure of type T"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to provide better and less formal explanation that the doc for type erasure.
In your case (Class casting) "If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs." means, that after type erasure a class cast is legal if the generic type arguments are in
"class-subclass relationship". Simple example for that:

```
    static class Bar {}
    static class FooBar extends Bar {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<FooBar> foobarList = (List<FooBar>) newList(Bar.class);
        List<Bar> barList = (List<Bar>) newList(FooBar.class);

        System.out.println("No cast class exception :)");
    }

    private static<T> List<?> newList(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just wanted to understand the theory that works behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

[4.6. Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)

> We write |T| for the erasure of type T.

Hence `|S|` is the erasure of type S.